# JSON array foreach loop with "where" attribute

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have a JSON array directly from an API and one piece of it looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "champion",
    "version": "4.4.3",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade",
            "stats": {
                "armor": 14.0,
                "armorperlevel": 3.8,
                "attackdamage": 55.0,
                "attackdamageperlevel": 3.2,
                "attackrange": 150.0,
                "attackspeedoffset": -0.04,
                "attackspeedperlevel": 3.0,
                "crit": 0.0,
                "critperlevel": 0.0,
                "hp": 395.0,
                "hpperlevel": 85.0,
                "hpregen": 5.75,
                "hpregenperlevel": 0.5,
                "movespeed": 345.0,
                "mp": 30.0,
                "mpperlevel": 45.0,
                "mpregen": 0.0,
                "mpregenperlevel": 0.0,
                "spellblock": 30.0,
                "spellblockperlevel": 1.25
            }
        },
```

and then it simply repeats this for every other champion.  I used cURL to turn that into a PHP array, which looks like this:

```
$url="api_url_blah";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$array = json_decode($result, true);
```

From there, I made a foreach loop to list all the champions and their "armor" stat, however the armor won't display but the champion name does:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array['data'] as $champs)
{

echo $champs['id']. "<br>";

    foreach($champs['stats'] as $stats) {
        echo $stats['armor'];
    }

$i++;
}
```

As I said, the champion name comes up but the second foreach loop is returning nothing.  Also, I was wondering what would be the most convenient way to make it so (after this works) I can call just one champion's stats based on a PHP variable and not all 118 of them at one time.

This is the var_dump() of the array:

```
array(3) { ["type"]=> string(8) "champion" ["version"]=> string(5) "4.4.3" ["data"]=> array(118) { ["Aatrox"]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(6) "Aatrox" ["key"]=> string(3) "266" ["name"]=> string(6) "Aatrox" ["title"]=> string(16) "the Darkin Blade" ["stats"]=> array(20) { ["armor"]=> float(14) ["armorperlevel"]=> float(3.8) ["attackdamage"]=> float(55) ["attackdamageperlevel"]=> float(3.2) ["attackrange"]=> float(150) ["attackspeedoffset"]=> float(-0.04) ["attackspeedperlevel"]=> float(3) ["crit"]=> float(0) ["critperlevel"]=> float(0) ["hp"]=> float(395) ["hpperlevel"]=> float(85) ["hpregen"]=> float(5.75) ["hpregenperlevel"]=> float(0.5) ["movespeed"]=> float(345) ["mp"]=> float(30) ["mpperlevel"]=> float(45) ["mpregen"]=> float(0) ["mpregenperlevel"]=> float(0) ["spellblock"]=> float(30) ["spellblockperlevel"]=> float(1.25) } }
```

Comment: @zerkms `var_dump()` what exactly?

Comment: `stats` is not a sub array of `data`

Comment: @user1895377: of every variable, if you don't have any particular suspect

Comment: my bad, not easy to decode json by eye

Comment: @zerkms if I use `var_dump` I get the huge array showing up on my page. I put the part that relates to the JSON in the post.

Comment: @user1895377: oh my god. **STOP** guessing, check with `var_dump` what actual data you have. You're in doubts about `$champs['stats']`? Check it. Confused what's in `$stats`? Check it. Programming is about facts, not about belief.

Comment: @user1895377 This lines of code will teach you more than you can ask `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need a second `foreach` loop. The following code should work:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array['data'] as $champs){
echo $champs['id'] . "<br/>" . $champs['stats']['armor'] . "<br/>";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: @andrew I don’t know. Perhaps the author of the question needs it to count the number of iterations. But then he/she should begin with `$i = 0`.